# Making Wordpress user metadata available to Rest-API

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, api-design, wordpress-rest-api

I am building an Ionic app that ties into my Wordpress website Rest API. While I have figured out how to populate post and page data, I am having a very difficult time populating user data.

Specifically, I am trying to access user data stored as usermeta by a third party plugin called UPME (User Profiles Made Easy). It is stored as user metadata in the database.

Here is an image of what I envision pulling from the API into the app.

[image: What I envision pulling]
For example, user_id: 43 meta_key: linkedin within the database.

Can someone please give me an example of what I can do in my functions.php to be able to populate every user with {...} meta_keys into the API for outside things to access?

EDIT: This is my understanding of what it should do

I need some function within Wordpress that makes the following available to my Rest-API:

```
• Get list of all users
    • For all users {
    • If user upme_user_profile_status: ACTIVE 
        • Get the following usermeta: [
        first_name
        last_name
        company_name
        company_title
        user_email
        business_phone
        facebook
        twitter
        linkedin
        ]
    }
```

This would be publicly accessible within the API.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) should help you. As well as [WP user query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for reference.

Example to display all subscribers in an unordered list.

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . '</span>';
}
```

Example of querying by a specific field.

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'display_name' ) ) );
// Array of stdClass objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span>';
}
```